# I want to give new data to the predict.lm. Why an object is not found in data.frame(), which I have used its logarithm in the linear regression model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

Using a dataset I built a model as below:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ as.numeric(X1) + as.factor(x2) + log(1 + x3) + as.numeric(X4) , dataset)
```

Then I build new data:

```
X1 <- 1
X2 <- 10
X3 <- 15
X4 <- 0.5
new <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3, X4)
predict(fit, new , se.fit=TRUE)
```

Then I get the Error below:

```
Error in data.frame(state_today, daily_creat, last1yr_min_hosp_icu_MDRD,  : 
  object 'X2' is not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this because of logarithm in the model?

Comment: are the lowercase `x2` and uppercase `X2` intentional? Is that the issue?

Comment: I think you may be getting into trouble with case-sensitivity?  Your original model uses `X1`, `x2`, `x3`, `X4` (unless you have mis-transcribed your actual `lm` call) ?

Answer (score 0):

A great way of looking at your problem another way is by constructing a self contained reproducible example. With no copy/pasting. This often gives you a fresh perspective and often teases out the weirdest bugs imaginable.

As flodel and Ben have pointed out, your problem is probably due to bad choice of variable names. I'm guessing you're using Rstudio, which in my opinion uses a terrible default font exactly for this reason. I can't tell x and X apart (easily).

Here is something similar to what you're trying to do, with all variable names correctly (un)capitalized.

```
xy <- data.frame(y = runif(20), x1 = runif(20), x2 = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE), x3 = runif(20))
fit <- lm(y ~ as.numeric(x1) + as.factor(x2) + log(1+x3), data = xy)
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = as.factor(3), x3 = 15))

         1 
0.05015187
```